# How to determine frame rates to detect for video classification

Tags: deep-learning, classification, cnn, computer-vision, image-preprocessing

I am building a Deep learning model for vibration, I have video inputs and I want to analyze this video for vibrations and categories these vibrations into various classes of vibrations, what considerations should I make while choosing the framerate, or sampling frequency of the frames from the video? Is there some sort of calculation or evaluation metric from the same?